# How to add number in each base case of recursion?(Python3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I want to add 1 to `ans` once a recursion branch reaches to where `n==0` but it fails.

I tried to assign `ans` at first and add `global` in front of it but they don't work.

It's all known that we can do it in the list. That is, the base case can process `ans.append(1)` for `ans=[]`. I'm confused about what I should do here.

```py
# Type: int n
def func(n)    
    def climb(n):
        if n == 0:
            ans += 1
        elif n < 0:
            ans += 0
        else:
            climb(n - 1)
            climb(n - 2)
    ans = 0  
    climb(n)
    return ans
```

Edit: In case you think whether I miss the `return` inside. No, the mechanism I want to copy is something like this, which works:

```py
# Type: string digits
def func(digits)
    dict = {...}

    def dfs(comb, i):
        if i == len(digits):
            ans.append(comb)
        else:
            for letter in dict[digits[i]]:    
                dfs(comb + letter, i + 1)
        
    ans = []
    if digits:
        dfs("", 0)
    return ans
```

Comment: The three last lines are not part of your function. If that is intended, please provide the function to which the final `return` belongs.

Comment: @trincot they should not be included in the `climb` function. This is a part of the solution of leetcode #70 climbing stairs. I want to count the number by revoking a recursion function and then return the final answer.

Comment: `return ans` is invalid outside of a function. And `ans` is not defined in your function. This code will not parse.

Comment: @trincot thanks for your comment, I modify my answer a bit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code cannot parse correctly:

- In your original question version, the `return` appeared outside of any function
- `ans` is not defined inside `climb`, and you cannot modify a variable outside of `climb` without using a declaration with `nonlocal` or similar

Not a problem, but `ans += 0` is a no-op.

Here is how the code can be made to parse and run:

```
def func(n):
    def climb(n):
        nonlocal ans
        if n == 0:
            ans += 1
        elif n > 0:
            climb(n - 1)
            climb(n - 2)
    ans = 0  
    climb(n)
    return ans

print(func(5)) # 8
```

However, this way of working makes `climb` a function with *side-effect*, i.e. it is not pure. This is not best practice. You could make `climb` pure by *returning* the value that has to be added. This also makes it unnecessary to wrap `climb` into another function:

```
def climb(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    return climb(n - 1) + climb(n - 2)

print(climb(5)) # 8
```

Note that neither represents an efficient solution. You could improve by using memoization.

Comment: thank you, that's what I want to ask. Sorry I didn't input the `def func(n)` in the original post. My mistake is to assign `global ans = 0` outside, but instead, I should type `nonlocal ans` inside the recursion function.  Because when I use `append` function for `ans=[]` (showd in the second example in my post), I don't need to assign the `nonlocal` thing inside. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: When you use `append` you don't assign a new value to `ans`, but just mutate it. That is allowed without `nonlocal`. But *assigning* a new value (using `=`) is a different story.